# Is "dawdle" a friendly word in everyday conversation or do we have a simpler one?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

> [daw‧dle](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/dawdle) /ˈdɔːdl $ ˈdɒː-/ verb [intransitive]      to take a long time
> to do something or walk somewhere:
>
> *Don’t dawdle – we’re late already!*
>
> **dawdle over**
>
> *I dawdled over a second cup of coffee.*

Is "**dawdle**" a friendly word in everyday conversation or do we have a simpler one?

For example, "**don't dawdle along the way and please don't talk to strangers!**" or "**don't hang about/around along the way and please don't talk to strangers!**"?

Comment: _Dawdle_ is fine in this context.

Comment: My mother said "Don't dawdle!" a lot when I was small.

Answer (score 1):

It is typical of the phrase  "don't dawdle" as spoken by parents to their children.  So it is fine in that context.

It is somewhat rarer to use in a positive command, eg "dawdle over".

Answer (score 1):

'*Dawdle*' is definitely not an 'unfriendly' word in that it is used informally, often by parents to children. It is not really a 'positive' word though, as the inference is that time is being wasted, so it is probably less common to hear it said about oneself. However, it works fine - an [example](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/dawdle) in the free dictionary "*dawdled through breakfast*" is very similar to your example.

A far more common expression in this context would be "I *lingered* over...". See [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20dawdled%2CI%20procrastinated%2CI%20lingered&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20dawdled%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20procrastinated%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20lingered%3B%2Cc0) for a comparison between similar expressions.

That said, if this is creative writing then it is often better to go with a choice of word or expression that is less common, so long as it works, and I'm fine with it.